# After updating bootstrap to v.5.3.2, js stops working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-5

After updating bootstrap from v.5.2.3 to v.5.3.2, this js stops working:

```
let trs = document.querySelectorAll('tbody>tr')
for (let i = 0; i < trs.length - 1; i++) {
    let v1 = parseFloat(trs[i].children[1].textContent)
    let v2 = parseFloat(trs[i + 1].children[1].textContent)
    let v3 = parseFloat(trs[i].children[2].textContent)
    let v4 = parseFloat(trs[i + 1].children[2].textContent)
    let v5 = parseFloat(trs[i].children[3].textContent)
    let v6 = parseFloat(trs[i + 1].children[3].textContent)
    if ((v1 == 0 || v1 * v2 < 0) && (v3 == 0 || v3 * v4 < 0) && (v5 == 0 || v5 * v6 < 0)) trs[i].style.background = '#cc9999'
    else if (((v1 == 0 || v1 * v2 < 0) && (v3 == 0 || v3 * v4 < 0)) || ((v1 == 0 || v1 * v2 < 0) && (v5 == 0 || v5 * v6 < 0)) || ((v3 == 0 || v3 * v4 < 0) && (v5 == 0 || v5 * v6 < 0))) trs[i].style.background = '#ff9999'
    else if ((v1 == 0 || v1 * v2 < 0) || (v3 == 0 || v3 * v4 < 0) || (v5 == 0 || v5 * v6 < 0)) trs[i].style.background = '#ffcccc'
}
```

How to reproduce:

```
$ yarn upgrade-interactive --latest
yarn upgrade-interactive v1.22.19
info Color legend :
 "<red>"    : Major Update backward-incompatible updates
 "<yellow>" : Minor Update backward-compatible features
 "<green>"  : Patch Update backward-compatible bug fixes
? Choose which packages to update.
? Choose which packages to update. bootstrap@5.3.2
info Installing "dependencies"...
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...

success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
└─ bootstrap@5.3.2
info All dependencies
└─ bootstrap@5.3.2
Done in 87.06s.
$ rake assets:clobber
I, [2023-12-05T20:42:47.290305 #5105]  INFO -- : Removed /home/alex/.disk_a/Rails/Heroku/masterpro_blog/public/assets
$ rake assets:precompile
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 1.29s.
yarn run v1.22.19
$ webpack --config ./config/webpack/webpack.config.js
asset application.js 191 KiB [emitted] [minimized] (name: application) 2 related assets
orphan modules 250 KiB [orphan] 61 modules
runtime modules 997 bytes 4 modules
cacheable modules 529 KiB
  ./app/javascript/application.js + 61 modules 250 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./app/javascript/nav_menu.js 212 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./app/javascript/sidebar_menu.js 361 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js 279 KiB [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.89.0 compiled successfully in 23073 ms
Done in 30.30s.
-----
$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.1.2 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 6.4.0 (ruby 3.1.3-p185) ("The Eagle of Durango")
*  Min threads: 5
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: development
*          PID: 5296
* Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000
* Listening on http://[::1]:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

After which the colored table lines stop appearing (live demo on [this](https://rails.masterpro.ws/bio/index) page).

I should add that in both cases I see this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textContent')
    at biorhythm-cbd62fd2773f4a61ed3caf9e8f6ad544356c8d32fd465b4624fca4386de89175.js:6:48
```

But before the bootstrap update the chart works fine, after the update - the days of "critical intersections" are no longer marked.

Any ideas to fix the application?